# Add <script> tag before </body> on only certain pages?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, plugin, extensions, javascript

I am fairly new to Joomla (using for less than a year) and I need to find a way to place a script tag before the  tag in joomla. This is for marketing (call tracking) purposes. I have seen some recommend the Flexi Code plugin/module, but I also saw it didn't give you a way to add it before the  tag. Normally, I'd add it to the template but the interesting dynamic here is that I only need it on certain pages, not all.

Any suggestions to help me get this done, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is also posted to SO at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39358322/1983389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit your template add this right before the closing  tag.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="analytics" style="none" />
```

Then you can use FlexiCustom Code module and publish it to the analytics position on any menu item you want.

Comment: Thank you - it turns out, the script needed to be added to every page so it became a bit easier to manage from there. I appreciate you responding.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to your template, you can use the following code

```
// Detecting Active Variables
$option   = $app->input->getCmd('option', '');
$view     = $app->input->getCmd('view', '');
$layout   = $app->input->getCmd('layout', '');
$task     = $app->input->getCmd('task', '');
$itemid   = $app->input->getCmd('Itemid', '');
```

and after at the right place in the template

```
if($itemid == 544) //replace 544 by your itemid
{
?>
   // tracking code here
<?php
}
?><body>
```

You can adapt the condition to match the page you need to track

Comment: Thank you - it turns out, the script needed to be added to every page so it became a bit easier to manage from there. I appreciate you responding. I'll keep this in mind in the event I need to come back to it.

Comment: add it on the main index.php of your template and it'll be available everywhere and don't forget to accept my answer if it help you.